# How to configure log4j2 with two root levels?

Tags: log4j2

I would like to configure log4j2 the following way:

1. Report ERROR events to Sentry.
2. Report INFO events to log file.

Something like:

```
    <Loggers>
        <!-- ERROR events are reported to Sentry. -->
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" />
        </Root>

        <!-- INFO events are reported to log file. -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="myLog" />
        </Root>
```

But of course I get error "Configuration has multiple root loggers. There can be only one.".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4j2 Different appender for different level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441759/log4j2-different-appender-for-different-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround that works for me:

```
    <!-- ERROR events are reported to Sentry. -->
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" />
    </Root>

    <!-- INFO events are reported to myLog. -->
    <Logger name="com" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="myLog" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="myLog" />
    </Logger>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can specify log level for appender as well -

```
<Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" level="error "/>
            <AppenderRef ref="myLog" level="info" />
        </Root>
</Loggers>
```

With this configuration, error and above level logs will be sent to `Sentry` appender. And info and above level logs (including error) will be sent to `myLog`

Answer (score 2):

I approached similar issue.
I've tried both suggested solutions and any of those were working for me. After few hours of trying to figure it out I have found out on logging.apache.org solution very similar to suggested one by Vikas Sachdeva.

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" level="error "/>
        <AppenderRef ref="myLog" level="info" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Without setting up level info directly in root my app was logging nothing. Adding this small change everything works great.