# Lo4j2 Logger generates empty file

Tags: java, log4j2

I am having trouble in making this simple log4j2 sample program work

**log42.properties**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
   <Appenders>
       <File name="LogToFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
           <PatternLayout>
               <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
           </PatternLayout>
       </File>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
       <Logger name="com.myapp" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
       </Logger>

        <!--<Root level="debug">
          <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>            
       </Root> -->
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Java code**

```
package com.lab;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.debug("Hello from Log4j 2");
        logger.info("Hello from Log4j 2");
        logger.error("Hello from Log4j 2");
    }


}
```

**pom**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.log4j2</artifactId>


    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>2.18.0</log4j.version>
        <disruptor.version>3.4.2</disruptor.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.lab.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It creates the app.log file, but it is empty. If I uncomment `<Root>` logger it writes log in the file. But the `<logger>` will not. What I am doing wrong? I referred lots of sample programs(and Apache documentation) but I am not able to understand why this is not working :`(

Comment: The logger name in your config XML is com.myapp. The package name in your class is com.lab.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. That was some very silly error (understanding) from me. I was basically trying to achieve what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64718539/870547).  Now I realize the name used in the Logger there is the package root name. Now the logger works, but not could not set different levels for logger and root. That's not working `<Loggers>
 <Root level="error">
  <AppenderRef ref="ErrorToFile" />
 </Root>
  <Logger name="com" level="debug">
  <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
 </Logger> 
</Loggers>`